# Insert null rows where needed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to preserve the structure of the results and replace the player id's with player firstnames. IE I want the nulls to stay where they are to preserve the ordering. see below:

Step 1) replace FK_WinnerID with FirstName and preserve the nulls.

[image]

Problem is sql statement is removing nulls

[image]

This is what it should look like:

[image]

Comment: Use a `RIGHT` join instead of a `LEFT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have

`FROM A LEFT JOIN B`

That means you want everything in `A` and matching records in `B`

But you want everything from `B` and matching records in `A` so you need to do either

`FROM B LEFT JOIN A`

OR

`FROM A RIGHT JOIN B`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FirstName
FROM Players right join TournamentPrizes
ON Players.PlayerID = TournamentPrizes.FK_WinnerID
WHERE FK_TournamentID=1043 
order by TournamentPrizes.Place ASC
```